# Class App\Http\requests\srequest does not exist using laravel 6 and heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

hi i have finished my project laravel 6 i have used a validation system, i have created a `srequest` which will verify the data entered in the form of adding a `salarie`, i have hosted my site in `heroku` i have found this error:`Class App\Http\requests\srequest does not exist`

**SalarieController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Salarie;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\requests\srequest;
class SalarieController extends Controller
{

public function store(
        $salarie = new Salarie($request->all());
        $salarie->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $salarie->save();
        session()->flash('success','salarie add successfully');
        return redirect('salaries');
      }
```

**app/Http/Requests/srequest.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'matricule'=> 'required',
          'nom'=> 'required|',
          'prenom'=> 'required',
          'cin'=> 'required',
          'salairenet'=> 'required',
          'chantier_id'=> 'required',
          'fonction_id'=> 'required'

        ];
    }
```

Comment: Where is the error ?

Comment: @Maraboc Class App\Http\requests\srequest does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
use App\Http\requests\srequest;
```

to

```
use App\Http\Requests\srequest;
```

You also dont need the `|` in `'nom'=> 'required|',`

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why does it work well locally?

Comment: I created a web app using laravel, my web app works well locally in my pc, but when I host it in heroku it gives me this error